# Why is the DHT22/AM2302 sensor output value divided by 10?

Tags: sensor, signal, temperature, humidity

[image: calculation of relative humidity value from sensor]

The divisor of 10 in the signal processing formula, where does it come from?

source: https://labprojectsbd.com/2020/05/17/how-to-interface-dht22-am2302-rht03-sensor-with-pic16f877a/

Comment: Please edit your question with enough text and images (credited to their owners) so that the question can be understood without reference to external sites if the link dies.

Answer (score 2):

The division by 10 is simply because that's the format the AM2302 outputs data in. See page 6 of [the datasheet](https://www.makerguides.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/DHT22-AM2302-Datasheet.pdf):

[image: Humidity and temperature calculations shown in the datasheet, showing that a raw humidity value of 0x0292 = 658 represents 65.8% humidity, and a raw temperature value of 0x10D = 269 represents 26.9 °C.]

As shown in the example, the humidity data is output in permille, and you need to divide by 10 to get percent. Likewise, the temperature data is given in tenths of a degree Celsius, so you divide by 10 to get degrees Celsius.

Comment: Oh, that's right, very useful information. Thank you very much